# jacorb: idl for 2.2.4 not working with java 1.8 installed

Tags: jacorb

I am on java 1.8.

I downloaded versions 2.2.4 and 3.9 from [here](https://www.jacorb.org/download.html). 2.2.4 is mentioned to work for java 1.3 or above:

```
Java JDK 1.3 or above is required for JacORB up to 2.3.0
```

When I run .../bin/idl command for a idl file using 3.9, it generates java mappings.

But same command for 2.2.4 gives:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jacorb.idl.parser
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: So use the newer one instead of the 17-year-old one. What reason do you have for using 2.2.4?

Comment: Client requirement.